# Database specialized in binary data storage

Tags: database, nosql, relational-database, storage, blob

I'm looking for a database that's specialized in storing binary data (files actually). This is the old discussion of storing [files in the database or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay). But I'm not looking for pros and cons, I'm looking for a database that is actually designed just for that.

It can be relational or NoSQL.

I can't seem to find any information on this and all my searches lead to post of pros and cons of storing files in the database, talking about MS-SQL's FILESTREAM etc.

I'm currently thinking of storing some files for an application and there are the two choices mentioned. Besides all the pros and cons on the two solutions, I'm also looking for something in between the two to make sure I have everything covered before actually choosing my poison.

Answer (score 2):

CouchDB has attachments: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Attachments

MongoDB has GridFS: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/